"Where along a hilly road would a car moving at a constant velocity exert the greatest amount of force on the road?"
This is a multiple choice question that is part of my high school physics review sheet. The correct answer is "at the dip, between two hills".
In my imagination, I would imagine it would be at the top of the hill, since centripetal acceleration would pull it towards the road as opposed to away from the road. Can someone help me understand this? Any help is appreciated.

Draw a free body diagram of the car in the two cases. What is the direction of the acceleration? Then, focus on the Normal Force by the road surface. Use Newton’s Third Law.

Centripetal force is not an additional force that you add to the other forces on the car. It is the net value of the other forces on the car - this net value must be non-zero if the path of the car is not a straight line.
In this case, the centripetal force is $W-N$ where $W$ is the weight of the car and $N$ is the normal force from the road (I am ignoring friction because that seems to be the intent of the question). Note that we take downward acting forces (such as $W$) to be positive.
When the car is at the top of a hill the centripetal force must act downwards to keep the car on the road. So $W-N_{top} > 0$ and hence $N_{top} < W$.
When the car is at the bottom of a dip the centripetal force must act upwards to keep the car on the road. So $W-N_{bot} < 0$ and hence $N_{bot} > W$.
So we can see that $N_{bot} > W > N_{top}$. Since the force exerted by the car on the road is equal and opposite to $N$ (by Newton's 3rd law) we can conclude that this force is greatest when the car is at the bottom of a dip.

Although speed is constant, the vehicle's velocity is not constant! Velocity is a vector. In order for the car to change direction a force is required. For motion around a curve this force is directed toward the center of rotation. This is the centripetal force.
Have you ever driven over a hump backed bridge at high speed, and the car left the road? In that case the weight of the car was insufficient to supply the centripetal force required for the car to follow the curvature of the road. Obviously, in this case the force the car exerts on the road is zero.
In cases where the speed is less, and the car stays on the road, the force its weight exerts on the road is also less. Part of the force due to its weight is required as a centripetal force to accelerate the car around the curve of the road.
At the dip, this is reversed. An extra force is required to accelerate the car vertically and this is supplied by increased force on the car from the road. in other words, that is by increased force exerted by the car on the road.
